# Changing the pointing arrow of the error prompt in Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, validation, semantic-ui

I am trying to change the pointing arrow of the error prompt in Semantic UI. The defualt is above and I want it below.
In React you can use pointing below but is doesn't work if not using React. That's my code:

```
$('.ui.form').form({
fields: {
  available: {
    identifier: 'available',
    rules: [
      {
        type: 'atLeastOneChecked',
        prompt: 'Please select at least one',
        pointing: 'below'
             
      }, ],
       },}
```